# PHP Pagination not functioning correcetly, stops on 6th page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I've recently got back into doing some PHP coding but have got stuck on something with PHP Pagination, it would seem that anything I tried either results in it not counting the pages and displaying on one page of results, or just stops at Page 6 and goes no further, I know with the data that is stored in the MySQL database, it should be showing 52 pages of results at 12 per page.

So I'm in need of some help, I thought it was working until I hit the won't go further than Page 6  after putting in 100's of entires into the database.

The code is as follows

```
<?php
    //
    //How to print date
    //
    if($print_date == 1)
    {
        $print_date = '%d.%m.%Y';
    }
    elseif($print_date == 2)
    {
        $print_date = '%m.%d.%Y';
    }
    elseif($print_date == 3)
    {
        $print_date = '%W, %M %D %Y';
    }
    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    } // if

    $get_matches = mysql_query("SELECT 
        O.OpponentName AS hometeam, OP.OpponentName AS awayteam,
        LM.LeagueMatchHomeGoals AS goals_home,
        LM.LeagueMatchAwayGoals AS goals_away,
        LM.LeagueMatchID AS id,
        DATE_FORMAT(LM.LeagueMatchDate, '$print_date') AS date
        FROM tplls_leaguematches LM, tplls_opponents O, tplls_opponents OP
        WHERE O.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchHomeID AND
        OP.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchAwayID AND
        LeagueMatchSeasonID LIKE '$defaultseasonid'
        ORDER BY LM.LeagueMatchDate");

    $get_matches = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Processing Fixtures");
    $query_data = mysql_fetch_row($get_matches);
    $numrows = $query_data[0];  
    $rows_per_page = 12;
    $lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
    $pageno = (int)$pageno;
    if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
        $pageno = $lastpage;
    } // if
    if ($pageno < 1) {
        $pageno = 1;
    } // if
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

    $get_matches2 = mysql_query("SELECT 
        O.OpponentName AS hometeam, OP.OpponentName AS awayteam,
        LM.LeagueMatchHomeGoals AS goals_home,
        LM.LeagueMatchAwayGoals AS goals_away,
        LM.LeagueMatchID AS id,
        DATE_FORMAT(LM.LeagueMatchDate, '$print_date') AS date
        FROM tplls_leaguematches LM, tplls_opponents O, tplls_opponents OP
        WHERE O.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchHomeID AND
        OP.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchAwayID AND
        LeagueMatchSeasonID LIKE '$defaultseasonid'
        ORDER BY LM.LeagueMatchDate, hometeam $limit",$connection)
        or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_matches2))
    {
?>
```

More to add, if I take out the first SELECT statement, I get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. It's just your code with some minor modifications.

```
<?php
    //
    //How to print date
    //
    switch ($print_date)
    {
    case 1:
        $print_date = '%d.%m.%Y';
        break;
    case 2:
        $print_date = '%m.%d.%Y';
        break;
        case 3:
        $print_date = '%W, %M %D %Y';
    }

    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    } // if

    $clause = "
        FROM tplls_leaguematches LM, tplls_opponents O, tplls_opponents OP
        WHERE O.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchHomeID AND
        OP.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchAwayID AND
        LeagueMatchSeasonID LIKE '$defaultseasonid'
        ORDER BY LM.LeagueMatchDate";

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num $clause";
    $result = @mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    $r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $numrows = $r[0];

    $rows_per_page = 12;
    $lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
    $pageno = (int)$pageno;
    if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
        $pageno = $lastpage;
    } // if
    if ($pageno < 1) {
        $pageno = 1;
    } // if
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

    $query = "SELECT 
        O.OpponentName AS hometeam, OP.OpponentName AS awayteam,
        LM.LeagueMatchHomeGoals AS goals_home,
        LM.LeagueMatchAwayGoals AS goals_away,
        LM.LeagueMatchID AS id,
        DATE_FORMAT(LM.LeagueMatchDate, '$print_date') AS date $clause $limit";

    $get_matches = mysql_query($query, $connection)
        or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_matches))
    {
?>
```

It's actually what @g.salakirov suggested but in the context of all the code you supplied. I haven't tested it, but it *should* work. (Famous last words. :D)

Comment: Note: If you're doing production work, you should look into [mysqli](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [prepared statements](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Most of the tutorials suck! I found [this article on SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/perfect-php-pagination/). I haven't read it yet, but it looks promising.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it throws up a fatal error.

Fatal error: SQL in /home/vhosts/binfieldfc.com/httpdocs/leaguetables/firstteam/index2.php on line 1688

Comment: which is line 
1688 $result = @mysql_query($query) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I forgot to set the database to call from using your corrected code. I had to reconnect the database after something else on the page kept closing the connection.

This works great now. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I just now read this comment. I'm glad it works. (56 min. later) Thanks for accepting. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysql_num_rows(resource $result) rather than mysql_fetch_row(resource $result) to get the number of rows in here: .

```
$get_matches = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Processing Fixtures");
$query_data = mysql_fetch_row($get_matches);
$numrows = $query_data[0];  
$rows_per_page = 12;
$lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
$pageno = (int)$pageno;
```

Alternatively, you can use a "count(*)" query in the beginning to get the number of entries, which will be significantly faster.

For example:

```
  $get_matches = mysql_query("SELECT 
    count(*) as resultCount
    FROM tplls_leaguematches LM, tplls_opponents O, tplls_opponents OP
    WHERE O.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchHomeID AND
    OP.OpponentID = LM.LeagueMatchAwayID AND
    LeagueMatchSeasonID LIKE '$defaultseasonid'
    ORDER BY LM.LeagueMatchDate");
```

Comment: Both of these, just returns 0 pages.